# How to generate a graph from datetime list (python3, pandas, matplotlib)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, graph

I'm having problems with visualizing a datetime data.

What I want to write is a code that generates a chart(graph) from a datetime date in format of (`%Y%m%d`) with python matplotlib library.

Below is my source code so far.

I wrote a code that generates list into a pandas DataFrame;

```
neg_date = pd.to_datetime(neg_date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
neg_date_data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':neg_date})
neg_date
```

(and the output is like :)

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-07-04', '2018-07-04', '2018-07-04', '2018-07-04',
               '2018-07-04', '2018-07-04', '2018-07-04', '2018-07-04',
               '2018-07-04', '2018-07-04',
               ...
               '2020-01-19', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-23',
               '2020-01-24', '2020-01-26', '2020-01-26', '2020-01-27',
               '2020-02-01', '2020-02-02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=149, freq=None)
```

Now I have to count the numbers of dates in each year-month. I'm having problem solving it. Here's the code that I've found from this site.

```
d = {}
neg_d = []
for date in neg_date_list:
    pubdate, time = date.split('T')
    year, month, date = pubdate.split('-')
    if year in d:
        if month in d[year]:
            d[year][month].append(date)
        else:
            d[year][month] = [date]
    else:
        d[year] = {month: [date]}
neg_d.append(d)
#print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
print(neg_d)

df = pd.DataFrame(neg_d, index = ['monthdate'])
df
```

(then the output)

```
2018    2019    2020
monthdate   {'07': ['04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '04', '0...   {'01': ['20', '01', '05', '14', '16', '19', '2...   {'01': ['02', '03', '03', '04', '04', '05', '0...
```

How can I extract the number of dates from each month, and then make a graph from it?

here's the whole code.

```
pos_date = [i.split('T', 1)[0] for i in pos_date_list]
pos_date = pd.to_datetime(pos_date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
pos_date_data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':pos_date})
neu_date = [i.split('T', 1)[0] for i in neu_date_list]
neu_date = pd.to_datetime(neu_date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
neu_date_data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':neu_date})
neg_date = [i.split('T', 1)[0] for i in neg_date_list]
neg_date = pd.to_datetime(neg_date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
neg_date_data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':neg_date})
neg_date
```

with the code below:

```
%matplotlib inline
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

startdate = "2018-07-04"
N = 20
drange = pd.date_range(startdate, periods=N, freq="MS")

#generate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Positive': pos_date ,'Neutral': neu_date ,
                   'Negative' : neg_date }, index=drange)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgDz0.png)

How can i fix the code to show the vary of number of dates?

Comment: I am thinking about `df = pd.DataFrame({'Positive': pos_date ,'Neutral': neu_date ,
                   'Negative' : neg_date }, index=drange)`, it is possible? Not each list has different length? If test last rows by `print (df.tail())` it is correct?

Comment: actually that line is not correct. that line makes error. So I'm finding for another solves.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(neg_date_data['datetime'].dt.month.rename('m'),
                 neg_date_data['datetime'].dt.year.rename('y'))
print (df)
y  2018  2020
m            
1     0     8
2     0     2
7    10     0
```

And then [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.plot()
```

Comment: If I have 2 more lists and to merge them in one graph,
how should I write a code?
with "pos_date_data", "neu_date_data", and "neg_date_date", 9
I want to generate the whole time graph that have number of dates as column, and the months as row. in range of:
startdate = "2018-07-04"
N = 20
drange = pd.date_range(startdate, periods=N, freq="MS")

Comment: the three lists "pos_date_data", "neu_date_data", "neg_date_data" I've got are containing different datetime items. that are actually datas extracted from comment information (publishedAt). then i seperated them by sentiments(positive, negative, neutral). I want to show the transformation variety.

Comment: @Jakharo - OK, can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @Jakharo - No new post, edit existing by https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60220931/edit

Comment: @jezreal - got it.